# Meteor server session variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

OK I have a icecast stream beign called in a meteor method like so:

```
var icy      = Meteor.npmRequire("icy");
var Future  = Meteor.npmRequire('fibers/future');
// URL to a known Icecast stream
Meteor.methods({
  //used in the RoomCtrl
  getmeta: function(url){

    MYFUTURE = new Future();
    // connect to the remote stream
    icy.get(url, function (res) {

      // log the HTTP response headers
      console.error(res.headers);

      // log any "metadata" events that happen
      res.on('metadata', function (metadata) {
        var parsed = icy.parse(metadata);
        console.log(parsed);
        if(MYFUTURE.isResolved()){
          MYFUTURE = new Future();
          MYFUTURE.return(parsed);
        }else{
          MYFUTURE.return(parsed);
        }
      });
      //THIS IS NEEDED GOD KNOWS WHY!
      res.on('data', function(data){
           //console.log(data);
      });
    });
    return MYFUTURE.wait();
  }
});
```

Which is great it updated the streams metadata on the server when the icecast server updates I'm also calling the method in using angular meteor like so :

```
$meteor.call('getmeta', $scope.pickedstation.ipdomain).then(
    function(data){
      console.log(data);
      $scope.streammeta = data;
    },
    function(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
```

which work on the first click, my problem arrises when the Icecast server pushes new data through the my server it's not then going through to the angular meteor method on the fron end... 
Any ideas?